# What is AuthUI deleting when AuthUI.getInstance().delete() is getting invoked?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm currently removing FirebaseUI Auth from my app and replacing it with "raw" Firebase Auth code.

So now I'm signing in *Google Sign-In* users via `GoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn()` and `GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()`, and signing out users via `GoogleSignInClient.signOut()`.

When deleting a Firebase User via `FirebaseUser.delete()`, I was also required to call `AuthUI.delete()`. I assume that `AuthUI` is a part of `FirebaseUI` which offers a common interface to all the OAuth providers. When searching for an equivalent `GoogleSignInClient.delete()`, I didn't find anything.

Since I'll no longer be using FirebaseUI Auth, this call to `AuthUI.delete()` will be obsolete, but I wonder what that invocation executed. Is it related to Google Sign-In? Will I still need to delete something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AuthUI.delete()` is used to delete the user and remove all the providers related to that user in one method call. The source code:

```
public Task<Void> delete(@NonNull Context context) {
        final FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            return Tasks.forException(new FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException(
                    String.valueOf(CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED),
                    "No currently signed in user."));
        }

        final List<Credential> credentials = getCredentialsFromFirebaseUser(currentUser);
        final CredentialsClient client = GoogleApiUtils.getCredentialsClient(context);

        // Ensure the order in which tasks are executed properly destructures the user.
        return signOutIdps(context).continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Void> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                task.getResult(); // Propagate exception if there was one

                List<Task<?>> credentialTasks = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Credential credential : credentials) {
                    credentialTasks.add(client.delete(credential));
                }
                return Tasks.whenAll(credentialTasks)
                        .continueWith(new Continuation<Void, Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public Void then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Exception e = task.getException();
                                Throwable t = e == null ? null : e.getCause();
                                if (!(t instanceof ApiException)
                                        || ((ApiException) t).getStatusCode() !=
                                        CommonStatusCodes.CANCELED) {
                                    // Only propagate the exception if it isn't an invalid account
                                    // one. This can occur if we failed to save the credential or it
                                    // was deleted elsewhere. However, a lack of stored credential
                                    // doesn't mean fully deleting the user failed.
                                    return task.getResult();
                                }

                                return null;
                            }
                        });
            }
        }).continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Void> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                task.getResult(); // Propagate exception if there was one
                return currentUser.delete();
            }
        });
    }
```

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/AuthUI.java

If you don't want to use `AuthUI` and you want to delete a user that signed in using Google provider then first you need to get the credentials, reauthenticate the user and delete.

For example:

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), null);
user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener...
```